# Opengl rotation doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinate-transformation

I try understand opengl, but I have many simple problems... I try rotate my object and I'm doing this:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[1]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(theProgram.get_programID(), "Texture1"), 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.1f);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _countof(tableIndices2), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

And my object is still in the same position.
What is wrong?

Comment: You are mixing the fixed-function OpenGL calls with the newer shader calls.

Comment: Also, just letting you know, I get answers to OpenGL questions much more quickly on the Game Development Stack Exchange site than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand my mistake, I'm a beginner and sometimes it's difficult for me.

Comment: Yes, I use shader and glVertexAttribPointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like `glRotate` are part of the See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) which is deprecated. This functions do not affect the vertices which are processed by a shader program.

See [Khronos wiki - Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL):

> In 2008, version 3.0 of the OpenGL specification was released. With this revision, the [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) as well as most of the related OpenGL functions and constants were declared deprecated. These deprecated elements and concepts are now commonly referred to as legacy OpenGL. ...

See [Khronos wiki - Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline):

> OpenGL 3.0 was the last revision of the specification which fully supported both fixed and programmable functionality. Even so, most hardware since the OpenGL 2.0 generation lacked the actual fixed-function hardware. Instead, fixed-function processes are emulated with shaders built by the system. ...

In modern OpenGL you have to do this stuff by yourself.

If you switch from Fixed Function Pipeline to today's OpenGL (in C++), then I recommend to use a library like [glm OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) for the matrix operations.

First you have to create a vertex shader with a matrix uniform and you have to do the multiplivation of the vertex coordinate and the model matrix in the vertex shader:

```
in vec3 vert_pos;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = model * vec4(vert_pos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Of course you can declare further matrices like projection matrix and view matrix:

```
in vec3 vert_pos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vert_pos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

In the c++ code you have to set set up the matrix and you have to set the matrix uniform:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> // glm::rotate
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>         // glm::value_ptr


glm::mat4 modelMat = glm::rotate(
    glm::mat4(1.0f),
    glm::radians(10.0f),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f) );

GLint model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram.get_programID(), "model");

glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMat));
```

See also the documentation of the [glm matrix transformations](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html).

Comment: I do something like this but this rotate all objects and I want rotate only one.

Comment: @senham You have to use an idividual model matrices for the differne objects (`modelMat1`, `modelMat2`... ). The model matrix defines the location and orientation of an object in the scene. Change the model matrix by `glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMat2));` right before you draw an object.

Comment: Now it's seems simple...sorry for confusing question...but I have project for study and not enought time I'm trying understand everyting during one day, and instead read everyting calmly with understand, I was trying find fast solution...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are mixing the old fixed-function calls (like glPushMatrix()) with the newer shader calls (like glUniform()). Functions like glPushMatrix() assume that you are giving the OpenGL driver more control over the graphics card (in other words, these functions take care of some newer OpenGL complications for you), which means that using newer function calls, like glUniform() can lead to random results (since you have no idea if you are disturbing the OpenGL driver's code).

Basically, all of the old fixed-function calls can be found here (this is actually OpenGL ES, which is opengl for embedded systems, or phones, in other words, but it is practically the same as opengl on the computer): [Fixed-Function Calls](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/).

I would recommend that you start learning the OpenGL ES 2 functions, which can be found here: [OpenGL ES 2 (Shader Function Calls)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/)

I think this is a good site to learn OpenGL ES 2 (even though you're not using OpenGL ES, this site teaches the concepts well). This site also uses Java, so ignore all the buffer information in the first tutorial (not to be confused with vertex and texture buffers, which are actually OpenGL, and not Java details): [Learn OpenGL Concepts](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // don't change to GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX
glLoadIdentity(); // good habit to initialize matrix by identity.
glPushMatrix();
```

Your call of function

```
glRotatef(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.1f);
```

should be same as

```
glRotatef(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1f);
```

meaning ten degrees by z-axis.
According to documentation of glRotatef(angle, x, y, z) - vector (x, y, z) is normalized to size 1 (if is not of size 1).

It should work. Is 10 degrees really significant to see result? Try to do something movable like.

```
glRotatef(rotZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1f);
rotZ += 5;
if (rotZ > 360) rotZ -= 360;
```